# Java/Processing, Finding the amount of files in a folder

Tags: java, file, processing

I've been working on a Processing Sketch (https://processing.org/) which involves counting how many files are in a folder (preferably the folder where the Sketch is located). Could someone please answer with some simple code that can work out how many files (.txt) are in a folder?

Can you also include any other information that was used to get that script to work such as libaries you imported, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
 File folder = File(folderpath)
 folder.listFiles().size
```

Comment: folder.listFiles().filter { file -> file.endsWith(".txt")  }.size

Comment: Good answer, but you should check if it's actually a folder with isDirectory() method (this checks if it exists as well)

Comment: `File` is part of javas core library. I.e. you already have it, nothing to setup. However, note that you may use the new library instead (NIO, also part of the core library). `Files.list(Paths.get(folderpath)).count()` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)).

Comment: I'm still having an issue with the folderpath name. It doesn't accept a string or just plain text. Could you please help by giving some sort of example, thanks!

Comment: Try this  
    File folder = File("yourfolder/")
    folder.listFiles().filter { file -> file.endsWith(".txt") }.size()

//yourfolder should be on your classpath.

Comment: It still doesn't work, it just says "The function File(String) does not exist". Can someone please help me solve this problem!

Comment: From what I know java.io.File object from your JDK accept for one String parameter for path name. This is available even from Java 6 (may be even before).